# C++ Programming Questions by vector<Object *> use and new Object()

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector, sdl-2

im really stuck right now...

**Summary:**

My C++ application crashes every time with an

```
Access Violation Reading Error on location 0x000000008
```

which must be an error by the use of multiple vectors of object pointers
where the objects are created with the new statement.

**-------------**

I want to train my skills by creating a simple GUI Engine with SDL2
and designed it like this:

**Create Engine class/object with extern (global)**

Because i want to pack all Engine related stuff like update functions
in one packet and init this via a init function:

**Create GUI class/object with extern**

I wanted this to also be in one "pack" and inside this class
i have multiple std::vector <#PointerToObject#> to keep
my created window objects alive on th global heap instead
of creating them temporary is this correct or is there a better
method to do so?

GUI.h

```
//...
class GUIWindow
{
    //...
    std::vector< GUIGadgetLable* > _guiGadgetLables;
    std::vector< GUIGadgetButton* > _guiGadgetButtons;
    //...
};
class GUI
{
    //...
    std::vector< GUIWindow* > _guiWindows;
    //...
    void createWindow(std::string title, int x, int y, int sx, int sy);
};
//...
extern GUI engineGUI;
```

GUI.cpp

```
//...
void GUI::createWindow(std::string title, int x, int y, int sx, int sy)
{
    this->_guiWindows.insert(this->_guiWindows.end(), new GUIWindow(title,x,y,sx,sy));
    return this->_guiWindows.at(this->_guiWindows.size()-1);
}
//...
GUI engineGUI;
```

I do this in many objects and my hirachy for GUI creation is like this:

GUI

1>GUIWindow

2->GUIGadgetLable

3-->GUIText

4--->ResourceTexture (createFromText)

2->GUIImage

3-->ResourceTexture (createFromFile)

2->GUIGadgetButton

3-->GUIText

Everything worked fine till i implemented my ResourceManager to capsule
the SDL texture rendering functions like load a Bitmap from a file into an SDL_Texture and create a texture from a text.

ResourceManager.h

```
class ResourceFont
{
public:
    TTF_Font* _font = NULL;
    int _fontSize = 3;
    std::string _fontFile = "";

    bool loadFromFile(std::string file, int fSize);

    void destroy();
};

class ResourceTexture
{
public:
SDL_Texture *_texture = NULL;

    SDL_Rect _size;
    SDL_Rect _position;

    std::string _data = ""; //File/Text
    bool _visible = true;

    bool _isText = false;
    int _fSize = 3;
    SDL_Color _textColor = {70,30,120};

    bool createFromFile(std::string file, int x, int y, float sx, float     sy);
    bool createFromText(std::string text, int fSize, int x, int y,  SDL_Color foreGround);
    bool changeText(std::string text);

    void resize(float sx, float sy);

    void update(int x, int y);
    void draw();
    void destroy();
};

class ResourceManager
{
public:
    std::vector< ResourceFont* > _resourceFonts;
    std::vector< ResourceTexture* > _resourceTextures;

    TTF_Font* addFont(std::string fontFile, int fSize);
};

extern ResourceManager engineResource;
```

The Texture things worked completely but after the implementation of the ResourceFont* Vector and the addFont Function (which uses TTF_Font to create a new font handle for the ResourceTexture::createFromText function) which is below the Program crashes with an access violation reading at adress 0x0...08 and this at the point where i call the

```
new ResourceFont()
```

or

```
return this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_font;
```

in my code so i think i got my heap corrupted but i dont know why if everything with the same methods worked well until this point?

ResourceManager.cpp

```
TTF_Font *ResourceManager::addFont(std::string fontFile, int fSize)
{
    std::cout << "GOIN "<< fSize << std::endl;
    if (this->_resourceFonts.size())
    {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i < this->_resourceFonts.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Compare: " << i << " Search: " << fSize << " Found: " << this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_fontSize << std::endl;
            if (this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_fontSize==fSize)   //this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_fontFile==fontFile&&
            {
                //std::cout << this->_resourceFonts.at(i) << std::endl;
                if (this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_fontSize==fSize)
                {
                    std::cout << "Found one " <<    &this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_font << std::endl;
                    return this->_resourceFonts.at(i)->_font; //Crashes sometimes here were it try to acces the object
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "Nope" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Create One" << std::endl << std::endl;
    this->_resourceFonts.insert(this->_resourceFonts.end(), new    ResourceFont()); //Crashes sometimes here
    this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-   1)->loadFromFile(fontFile,fSize);

    if (this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-1)->_font)
    {
        return this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-   1)->_font;
    }
    else
    {
        this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-   1)->destroy();
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Have anybody an idea how to solve this?

Thank you :)

Comment: "I will upload the whole code in a couple of minutes."... please don't... Even as it currently is, you should probably edit your post only to one question and only the relevant info, otherwise with its current size and meandering nature, it's liable to be flagged into oblivion. Let's try to deal with one thing at a time. Or if you get the code working and just want a general review, try the handily named sister site Code Review.

Comment: Yeah sorry i made a little summary the problem seems to be caused by the use of vectors with object pointers and the object creation with new. But i cant find the reason why it tries to read the adress 0x0...8

Comment: Use valgrind; if this fails, use a debugger.

Comment: `this->_resourceFonts.size()-   1`  Please replace this line and lines looking like this with `_resourceFonts.back()`.

Comment: @kfx i debugged it with ollyDebug and get the error i mentioned above at a command where the program checks if the variable is null at the position EDX+8 but the register is empty at this time and so the access violation is generated

Comment: it tries to read the address 0x0...8 because you try to access a member of an object by null ptr to it: `AObject obj = nullptr; obj->some_member;`. Now you need to find how nullptr went to your vector

Comment: @AndyT the nullptr is inserted at my addFont function where i create a new object with "new" but i dont know why it is corrupted, it seems that the program crashes also at this point where the new object is created

Comment: Are you deleting all raw ptrs in those vectors ? Why not just use smart ptrs ?

Comment: @old_mountain i made sure that every object is correct destroyed and then removed from the vector and to this point where it crashes no object ist deleted, the problem is where the object in the vector is created.
i will look up about smart ptrs thank you

Comment: Surely the debugger told you a bit more. What's the line of code where the access violation occurs? What is it trying to read, exactly? Also, maybe you can boil this down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that'll make it easier for you and us…

Comment: @mindriot GDB told me something interesting:

[New Thread 1408.0x15cc]
[New Thread 1408.0x131c]
[New Thread 1408.0xc94]
[New Thread 1408.0x20c]
[New Thread 1408.0xb98]
[New Thread 1408.0x17e4]
[New Thread 1408.0xdf8]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6cd0390f in libfreetype-6!FT_Get_Char_Index ()
   from Project\Release\libfreetype-
6.dll

It looks like the DLL causes the error. I try to remove the TTF DLL relevant Code.

Comment: Nothing... just another segmentation fault but now in ??()

GDB Backtrace:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040270a in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0040270a in ?? ()
#1  0x00402600 in ?? ()
#2  0x0040142b in ?? ()
#3  0x004010fd in ?? ()
#4  0x773c9882 in ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain ()
   from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#5  0x773c9855 in ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain ()
   from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
#6  0x00000000 in ?? ()    Because he try to access adress 0x0 now

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the real error, but the code is too large to fit in a comment.

At the very end of `AddFont` you have:

```
if (this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-1)->_font)
{
    return this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-   1)->_font;
}
else
{
    this->_resourceFonts.at(this->_resourceFonts.size()-   1)->destroy();
    return NULL;
}
```

This code tests for a non-null `_font`, which means that in the `else` part the `_font` member *is* null. And it is still left in the `_resourceFonts` vector.

Comment: thank you thats right i missed it. i added    this->_resourceFonts.erase(this->_resourceFonts.end());
before return NULL; and now it crashes at this point where it tries to erase the pointer from the vector?!

Comment: I removed the "delete this;" part so that i dont have to call erase and it crashes again. The strange thing is that it saves a correct pointer to the object and access the correct pointer to the object? I dont understand why it then crashes if it has the correct adress.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like i found the Problem:

If i use the ResoruceManager::addFont() direct in every function instead of saving it in an extra TTF_Font* var the program runs normal.